# Usage of data structures

Tags: data-structures

I have a common question about the usage of data structures in coding assessments. When giving any coding assessments (with hackerrank etc) for example if an array is passed as an argument to a function which needs to be completed, is it acceptable to restore the data to hashmap or other data structures according to the problem? Well I know there is no restriction explicitly but while evaluating performance would that matters?

Comment: If you're asking whether it's worthwhile to create a data structure from existing data in order to accelerate operations on that data, the answer is "sometimes".

Comment: Yes, data structure choice affects performance - that's largely the point of there being different data structures. You'd need to understand the complexity and frequency of the operations you want to perform on the different data structures to be able to pick the best one (and use it efficiently).

Comment: Okay. I think I need to rephrase and ask in this way. Suppose the function input is an array and expected output is array, however, I feel its good to use Hashmap for doing operations on data, Is it a good idea to feed the array to hashmap and again back to array in case of giving online assessments especially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach would be to try to avoid copying the received array into some other data structure if this data structure of yours does not really give you an upper hand with regards to performance. However, if the new data structure enhances the performance of your algorithm, then YES you should do it without hesitation as it would only be a linear operation ( O(n) ). Though this is just my humble opinion, hope you get a better answer for this.

Comment: Okay. I think I need to rephrase and ask in this way. Suppose the function input is an array and expected output is array, however, I feel its good to use Hashmap for doing operations on data, Is it a good idea to feed the array to hashmap and again back to array in case of giving online assessments especially.

Comment: You should avoid it as online assessments tend to test your code with huge data sets hence your code might end up failing certain tests as copy action adds some additional overhead. However, if it significantly improves the performance of your algorithm, then you should definitely consider using HashMap as it makes life simpler quite often.

Answer (score 0):

There have no straight forward answer for these type of questions. The answer totally depends on the problem you are solving.
For example, if someone asks should I use linear search or binary search to find a value from a unsorted array. Even if the binary search is much more faster than the linear search, still using binary search is not always efficient. 
For instance, if he/she has to search in the array for just one time then using binary search will give him/her complexity of O(nlogn) as the array needs to be sorted first, where he/she can search using linear search with O(n) complexity.

I hope you got the answer :)